# What are the main differences between running IE10 in desktop mode and metro mode on a windows tablet?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, internet-explorer-10

I'm debugging a application that runs great on IE10 desktop version on a windows 8 tablet, but when I'm opening the same app in the metro version of IE10, tapping on buttons in the interfaces doesn't seem to work. This has something to do with how IE10 handles the taps on the screen.

Is there a clear and complete list of differences between IE10 in metro mode and IE10 in desktop mode on a touch enabled screen? If yes, what are those differences?