# When IE10 is in Metro Mode is it Effectively a Different Browser Version Than Desktop Mode?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

Right now, we're dealing with bugs in our web app that only seem to be occurring when IE10 is in Metro mode. When IE is run from the desktop the errors do not occur.

Questions:

- When IE10 is in Metro mode, is it effectively a different browser version than when it's run from the desktop? Would this explain some of the behavioral differences we're seeing?
- If it is a different version, is there a resource that explains the differences?

  - Specifically worried about rendering engine differences or JavaScript versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the main differences between running IE10 in desktop mode and metro mode on a windows tablet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856056/what-are-the-main-differences-between-running-ie10-in-desktop-mode-and-metro-mod)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are two different versions of IE10: Metro/Windows UI and the desktop version.  Here is the official documentation from Microsoft that explains the similarities and differences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/hh771832.aspx

Comment: -1, because 1) the info is in a link and 2) the info is useless for developers and this question specifically; differences in rendering or JavaScript execution are not even mentioned.